# Prove that $\mathcal M : = \left \{E \in \mathcal B_{\Bbb R^2}\ |\ \lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (E+x) = \lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (E) \right \}$ is a monotone class.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

> Let $(\Bbb R^2, \mathcal L_{\Bbb R^2}, \lambda_{\Bbb R^2})$ be the Lebesgue measure space on $\Bbb R^2.$

Prove that $$\mathcal M : = \left \{E \in \mathcal B_{\Bbb R^2}\ |\ \lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (E+x) = \lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (E) \right \}$$ is a monotone class of subsets of $\Bbb R^2,$ for any $x \in \Bbb R^2.$

I have proven that $\mathcal M$ is closed under countable increasing unions. But I find it difficult to prove that it is closed under countable decreasing intersections as well. Let $\{F_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a decreasing sequence of subsets in $\mathcal M$ i.e. $F_n \in \mathcal M$ and $F_n \supseteq F_{n+1},$ for all $n \geq 1.$ Let $F = \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n.$

We need to show that $F \in \mathcal M$ or in other words $\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (F+x) = \lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (F).$ Let $E_n = F_n^c,$ $n \geq 1.$ Since $F_n$'s are decreasing, $E_n$'s are increasing. Let $E = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n.$ Then by De Morgan's laws it is easy to see that $F = E^c.$

Since $E_n$'s are increasing to $E$ and since $\mathcal M$ is closed under countable incresaing unions (I assume it as I have proved it already) so it follows that $\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (E + x) = \lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (E).$ Therefore \begin{align*} \lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (F^c+x) & = \lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (E + x) \\ & = \lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (E) \\ & = \lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (F^c) \end{align*}

This shows that $F^c \in \mathcal M.$ So if we can show that $\mathcal M$ is closed under complementation then we are through. But I find difficulty to prove this part. I know that for any $E \subseteq \Bbb R^2$ and for any $x \in \Bbb R^2$ we have $(E+x)^c = E^c +x.$ If $E \in \mathcal M$ then by using the previous equality I get $$\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (E^c + x) = \lambda_{\Bbb R^2} ((E+x)^c).$$ But now I got stuck. Because if $\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (E) = +\infty$ then we don't have a valid expression for $\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} ((E+x)^c).$ Can anybody please help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't $\lambda_{\mathbb R^2}(E+x)$ always equal to $\lambda_{\mathbb R^2}(E)$?

Comment: What do you mean by always equal to @Stephen Montgomery-Smith?

Comment: I mean that $\mathcal M = \mathcal B_{\mathbb R^2}$.

Comment: How do you prove that? The way of proving it is along the lines I argued. If we can prove that $\mathcal M$ is a monotone class we are through. Do you see why @Stephen Montgomery-Smith?

Comment: $\lambda_{\mathbb R^2}$ is translation invariant.  It is a well known property of Lebesgue measure.

Comment: No it is not proved in my book. It has been tried to prove as a consequence.

Comment: I think this is not the way to prove it, as your proof has the problem you noted.

Comment: No in my book it has been left as an exercise @Stephen Montgomery-Smith.

Comment: If you have some other known way please provide it to me@Stephen Montgomery-Smith.

Comment: Show $\mathcal M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @Stephen Montgomery-Smith It is easy to prove that $\mathcal M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra if we can prove that $\mathcal M$ is closed under complimentation. That's the only place I got stuck. Did you go through my attempt above?

Comment: @Phibetakappa may you already use the result that  measures which are equal on a generator which is stable under intersections are equal on the whole sigma algebra?

Comment: @Gono can you please be more explicit about what you are trying to say?

Comment: For proving that $\mathcal M$ is closed under countable increasing unions I used the fact that measures are continuous from below.

Comment: Let $\mathcal{E}$ be stable under intersection and it holds $\mu_1 = \mu_2$ on $\mathcal{E}$  with both are $\sigma$-finite then it holds $\mu_1 = \mu_2$ on $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$.
Known result?

Comment: @Gono are you talking about Caratheodory extension? But this is possible only when both $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are $\sigma$-finite measures as far as I know.

Comment: @Phibetakappa you are right (as mentioned already) but your $\lambda$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: Yeah. Then what are you trying to argue from here @Gono?

Comment: @amWhy what have you edited in the body? I can't see any error in my argument. Oops...

Comment: And be aware that the result I stated is slightly different from Caratheodory extension… or it's named differently in your book. But nevertheless: You have well known generators for $B_{\Bbb R^2}$. So if you consider a new measure $\tilde{\lambda}$ defined by $$\tilde{\lambda}(E) := \lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (E+x)$$ it's easy to show that $\tilde{\lambda}$ and $\lambda_{\Bbb R^2}$ are equal on those generators hence they are equal on $B_{\Bbb R^2}$. So it follows $\mathcal{M} = B_{\Bbb R^2}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111342/discussion-between-gono-and-phi-beta-kappa).

Comment: Is $\overline {\lambda}$ $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: Yes, $\bar\lambda=\lambda$ on rectangles (this you can prove by hand), so $\bar\lambda$ is also $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: Yeah you are right @Reveillark. Very nice argument. Got it. Thanks for your invaluable suggestion.

Comment: @Gono I urge you to post it as an answer whatever you have commented above. Your ideas are amazing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have well known generators for $B_{\Bbb R^2}$ which are stable under intersections, e.g. all rectangles.

If we consider a new measure $\tilde{\lambda}$ defined by $$\tilde{\lambda}(E) := \lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (E+x)$$ it's easy to show that $\tilde{\lambda}$ and $\lambda_{\Bbb R^2}$ are $\sigma$-finite and equal on those generators so it follows that they are equal on $B_{\Bbb R^2}$ and we get $\mathcal{M} = B_{\Bbb R^2}$

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different way of getting the invariance of the Lebesgue measure:

1. First, argue that for every rectangle $R$, $\lambda(R+x)=\lambda(R)$.
2. Call $R\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ a dyadic rectangle if it is of the form $R=I\times J$, where $I$ and $J$ are half-open intervals (of the form $[,)$) whose endpoints are dyadic rationals (i.e. of the form $k/2^n$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$). Show that every open set $U$ is a countable union of pairwise disjoint dyadic rectangles.
3. Put (1) and (2) together to show that $\lambda(U+x)=\lambda(U)$ for every open set $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. This uses that, if $R$ and $S$ are disjoint, then so are $R+x$ and $S+x$.
4. Use the outer regularity of the Lebesgue measure (plus the fact that $U+x$ is open whenever $U$ is) to show that $\lambda(A+x)=\lambda(A)$ for any measurable set $A$.

By the way, this holds for any dimension, not just $2$. You just need to replace rectangles by their higher dimensional analogues.

Comment: Only $(2)$ is bit difficult; remaining arguments are straightforward. Though I know that the dyadic rationals are dense in the reals.May be that's roughly the reason why $(2)$ holds.